# Terminate a Azure Virtual machine and belongings

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I want to Terminate a **Azure Virtual machine** and all of it's belongings.

**What i have done --**

```
I have stopped the Virtual machine
```

It seems the by stopping Virtual Machine all of it's belongings are also stopped.

Now my question is --

```
Since i don't need this Virtual Machine ever,
how can i remove everything which belongs to a Azure Subscription !
```

Any one knows any solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the cloud service which holds the vm. Click on delete button. You will get an option to delete cloud service and its deployment.  Just do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using  azure resource manager deployment model and have logically grouped all the resources for that virtual machine under  that group. Deleting the resource group itself will remove everything related to that VM.